# Cambiar el color de fondo de una página utilizando PHP

Tags: php

¿Alguien sabe cómo cambiar el color de fondo de mi página si se cumplen las condiciones establecidas en la sentencia condición?

> Notice: Undefined variable: body in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\inc\header.inc.php on line 11

index.php

```
if(isset($body) || $body == true)
{
    echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
} else {
    echo '<body style="background-color:orange">';
}

?>
```

Comment: La advertencia que te lanza es clara y concisa, la variable `$body` con la que intentas hacer la comprobación dentro del `if` no está definida. ¿De donde viene esa variable? ¿En algún momento previo al código que has compartido le asignas algún valor a dicha variable?

Comment: yo pienso, isset(($body == true))?

Comment: @DiegoSagredo eso no funcionará porque estás haciendo el `isset` del resultado de `$body == true`, pero como `$body` no está definida, te seguirá lanzando el error

Comment: @AlavaroMontoro perfectamente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema como bien dice [Hechi en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25063/cambiar-el-color-de-fondo-de-una-p%C3%A1gina-utilizando-php#comment40539_25063), es que la variable `$body` (que usas en la condición del `if`) no está definida. Y la gracia es que una de las comprobaciones es para ver si está definida o no.

El problema es que estás conectado con un O (`||`), cuando deberías estar usando un Y (`&&`). Cuando usas `||`, se comprueban todas las condiciones en orden hasta que una sea verdadera (y se ignoran el resto); cuando usas un `&&`, se comprueban todas las condiciones en orden hasta que una sea falsa (y se ignora el resto). Estás comprobando que `$body` esté definida: no lo está, por lo tanto es falso, pero como usas `||`, se pasa a la siguiente condición `$body == true` y esa es la que te lanza el error porque estás intentando acceder una variable no definida.

La solución sería sencilla, usa un Y (`&&`):

```
if(isset($body) && $body == true)
{
    echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
} else {
    echo '<body style="background-color:orange">';
}
```

Comment: Entendo claro, buen explica. Gracias amigo

Comment: ¿Qué hay de `<body style="background-color: <?PHP echo (isset($body) && $body == true)? 'white': 'orange'; ?>">`?

Comment: @PaulVargas Esa sería una forma más concreta/limpia de hacerlo, puse el código así porque quería ajustarme lo máximo posible a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

@AlvaroMontoro, consulta por ejemplo

```
if(isset($body) && $body == true)
{
    echo '<body style="background-color:white">'; --> login.php cuando si acepta "Entrar" index.php abajo color orange
} else {
    echo '<body style="background-color:orange">'; --> "Entrar" al sitio index.php
}
```